# How to exclude/ignore referenced project(s) analysis from SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube5.1.2

I have a solution which has three projects (X,Y,Z).  Z referenced in Y , Y in X . When I start Analysis with MSBuild SonarQube Runner on project X, it is analyzing Y and Z as well. Do we have any solution for ignoring recursive analysis ?

Note: I can not breakup solution file into multiple solution files & refer dll's rather than projects.

Answer (score 2):

in sonar -> administration -> General Settings -> Analysis Scope
set "Source File exclusions" like that:
file:**/ProjectName/* * (without spaces between * *)

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/ad78d4db8c0bda657d67d17a9c6e78d9.png]

Answer (score 1):

You can statically mark individual projects as being included/excluded by setting a property in the MSBuild file. See the online docs [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/appendix-2.md#excluding-artefacts-from-analysis).

If you want to do something more dynamic have a look at the [advanced config appendix](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/appendix-3.md).

Answer (score 1):

you can add the tag  into ProjectReference 'Y' of your project 'X' configuration.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" $(ProjectGuid) != '' AND $(SonarQubeExclude) == '' ">
    <SonarQubeExclude Condition="$(ProjectGuid) == 'C999E666-3666-9990-B666-9999E666' " >true</SonarQubeExclude>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This must be added on X project and the id C999E666-3666... is the id that you want excluded.

More information on:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/appendix-2.md