# SonarQube - Excluding files and folders [Entire .Net Project (csproj)]

Tags: sonarqube

[image]I am trying to exclude some folders from Sonar scan through VSTS build. We have used Sonar plugin for MSBuild.

If I use the exclusion pattern as `**/*.cs` then it is excluding all the .cs files. My goal is to exclude whole folder from scan.
I have tried the following patterns but none of them seems to work

```
**/folder/*
**/folder/*.cs
**/folder/**
**/folder/**/*
**/folder/**/*.cs
folder/*.cs
folder/**/*.cs
folder/**/*
folder/**
folder/*
```

Please help in getting the correct pattern.

I want to exclude This Issue project from the scan.

Comment: `folder/**` or `**/folder/**` should work without a problem. Remember, that the root directory is the one with *.csproj file. Maybe try to edit your post and show us your folder structure + what you have in SonarQube.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct that the root directory is *.csproj. DO you know how to exclude any project from the analysis or how o exclude an entire csproj file from scan so that not files inside that project get scanned?

Comment: There is partial solution to this problem in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816611/sonarqube-msbuild-scanner-doesnt-exclude-files-from-analysis

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude an entire C# project by setting the MSBuild property *SonarQubeExclude* to *true* in the project file. See this post: [How to exclude/ignore referenced project(s) analysis from SoanrQube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563682/how-to-exclude-ignore-referenced-projects-analysis-from-soanrqube)

Comment: This solution anyhow works, but this will also include a time effort to implement and in our problem we have multiple builds for same solution. In some of them do not need sonar on solution x but in some we need. So if there is something that we can implement through Sonar server side then  it would be better.